# Upgrading java 8 to 17, jaxb to jakarta generates source classes from wsdl with javax.xml.bind package and complains about package does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jaxb, jakarta-migration

We are in process of upgrading Spring boot 2.7 to 3.2

As part of this upgrade, I upgraded java 8 to java 18 and some other necessary updates too. I updated jaxb schema to jakarta ee and version 3.0.

I changed namespace from java.sun.com to jakarta.ee

Similar changes are made in global-bindings.xml, jaxb-bindings.xml and wsdl-bindings.xml as well

cxf-codegen-plugin is being used for generating source files from wsdl.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <defaultOptions>
                        <bindingFiles>
                            <bindingFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/global-bindings.xjb</bindingFile>
                        </bindingFiles>
                    </defaultOptions>
                    <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                    <wsdlOptions>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <wsdl>src/main/resources/OneAPI.wsdl</wsdl>
                            <extraargs>
                                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>http://example.com/One/OneAPI=com.practice.OneAPI</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>http://practice.com/OneAPI=com.practice.OneAPI</extraarg>
                            </extraargs>
                        </wsdlOption>
                    </wsdlOptions>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Maven build still generates source files in target directory of project with import statement javax.xml.bind.* complains about package does not exist.

I saw many posts similar to this, but none of them resolved my issue.

Am I missing something which I should be taking care as part of upgrade to jakarta?

Comment: Without a full pom file etc. also have you read the upgrade guide of SB (2.7->3.0->3.1->3.2).. generating means you use XSD/WSDL's ? How do you do that?

Comment: Did you try with : `org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:4.0.4` ?